# Is mylyn, egit and jgit jars removed from the eclipse SDK

Tags: eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

Hi we were using eclipse sdk 4.4 where mylyn, egit and jgit jars were present but now with the latest sdk or any sdk downloaded from eclipse website that doesn't have these jars.

Is there any alternative for this jars or do we have any other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The **Eclipse SDK** does not and has **never contained Mylyn, JGit/EGit**, but the **Eclipse IDE packages contains them** (see [archive of Eclipse SDK 4.4](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/)).

Download:

- [Eclipse SDK, Platform Runtime, etc.](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) - not containing Mylyn, JGit/EGit, etc.
- [Eclipse IDE packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) - containing Mylyn, JGit/EGit, etc.

The **Eclipse SDK** is from the **[Eclipse project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse)**. There are many Eclipse projects, but only one of them is the *Eclipse* project with its sub-projects [Eclipse Platform](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform), [Eclipse JDT](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt), [Eclipse PDE](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.pde) and [Eclipse Equinox](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.equinox).

The **[Eclipse Packaging Project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.packaging)** builds from artifacts of these and of other Eclipse projects the **IDE packages**. 2023-12 is currently the latest quarterly release and based on Eclipse 4.30. [Eclipse 4.4 was part of Eclipse Luna, which was released more than a decade ago in June 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases) (see [archive of Eclipse Luna containing Mylyn, JGit/EGit, etc.](https://archive.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201502271000/plugins/)).

Comment: Eclipse 4.4 was we were using till now. Now due to some requirements we are trying to use 4.17 version in that mylyn, egit and jgit is not there. Is there alternative in the latets releases or any workaround.

Comment: Eclipse 4.17 was part of the [simultaneous release 2020-09](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2020-09) which can still be [downloaded here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-09/r) and which also contains Eclipse Mylyn 3.25.2. But it is highly recommended to use the latest quarterly simultaneous release instead. 2020-09 (4.17) will likely not work with current Java versions and maybe not with current operating systems, especially not with recent macOS versions (e.g. a couple of adaptations were necessary for macOS Big Sur).

Comment: The p2 update site of the latest simultaneous release is [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/).

Comment: we doing plugin development for eclipse. while building source code with eclipse sdk we are getting error like this

Comment: [java]     Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.egit.ui_0.0.0.
     [java]     Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jgit_0.0.0.

Comment: even i checked in the plugin folder of installed sdk there also there was no jars related to egit, jgit and mylyn are not there

Comment: Downloaded from here https://www.filehorse.com/download-eclipse-64/54804/

Comment: That's not the official download of the Eclipse SDK. And as already said, the Eclipse SDK does not contain Mylyn and EGit. Nowadays, [Maven Tycho](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html) is the way to build Eclipse-based (RCP) applications.

Comment: Ours is ant project we are building project with this commands ant -f accurevBuild.xml -Dac.eclipse.dir=C:\Eclipse_Sdk\sdk_4.17\eclipse -DpdeVersion=3.10.800.v20200410-1419 -DequinoxVersion=1.5.800.v20200727-1323 -Dac.build.equinoxVersion=1.5.800.v20200727-1323 -Dac.build.pdeVersion=3.10.800.v20200410-1419  -Dac.build.version=2021.1 -Dac.accurev.bin="C:\Program Files\AccuRev\bin\accurev.exe" -Dac.build.trans=1173101212

Comment: Dac.eclipse.dir=C:\Eclipse_Sdk\sdk_4.17\eclipse   this is the eclipse package we are using but this giving the error like mylyn, egit and jgit are not present.  Any solution to resolve this. ANd i downloaded from eclipse website only

Comment: As has already been said [tag:tycho] is now the only supported build method. Trying to diagnose problems with other build systems is going to be extremely difficult. I don't recognise that ant script at all.

Comment: We need to migrate from ant project to maven. Need to use tycho to build the project rite? That recommended way to resolve build issues.?

Comment: Yes, you need to migrate from Ant-based PDE Build to Maven Tycho, as PDE Build is not supported anymore since years. Also, PDE Build handles transitive dependencies differently than Tycho, which means you may face issues that are impossible or difficult to fix with PDE Build. From my own experience, sticking with PDE Build was a waste of time already years ago.